# How to pronounce 体?

Tags: pronunciation

Does anyone have any tips on how to pronounce 体{からだ}. I can do ら and だ fine by themselves/in different words, but when they're right next to each other I really struggle to make both sounds consecutively and quickly . Also, does anyone know of any other common words that have an "r" and "d" sound right next to each other?

Comment: Tips... would vary according to what language you speak. Are you an American?

Comment: Japanese kids also often struggle with pronunciations of からだ, サラダ, たまご etc, no? I remember many kids around me saying かだら, サダラ, たがも.

Answer (score 1):

The conjunction けれど and the loanword サラダ (salad) also have adjacent r and d sounds. To practice pronouncing this, simply begin by pronouncing it a bit more slowly but clearly, and then faster. Also, try repeating after native speakers (in anime/TV drama/etc). Practice makes perfect, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try pronouncing the "r" in ら with the tip of your tongue barely touching your palate near your front teeth (but without actually touching the teeth themselves.. kind of like a soft だ but with the tongue even further back away from the teeth).  This will get you closer to a natural Japanese "r" sound, and I think you will find it is much easier to do.

The (American) English "r" has the back of one's tongue just barely touching towards the back of the palate.  It's difficult to segue to and from this sound when adjacent to a sound like だ where the tip of the tongue has move to the front of the mouth.